# Android/SQLite - Bit operation on WHERE clause

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, bit-manipulation, where-clause

I'd like to know if it's possible to do in Android something like this:

```
public Cursor getFlowsByCategory(int type, int categoryID, int limit) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    final String[] columns = {ID, FLAGS, SUBJECT, AMOUNT, AMOUNT_NO, CATEGORY};
    final String selection = "((" + FLAGS + " & ?) >> 1 = ?) AND (" + CATEGORY + " = ?)";
    final String[] selectionArgs = {Integer.toString(Flow.FLOW_TYPE), Integer.toString(type), Integer.toString(categoryID)};

    return db.query(TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, ID + " DESC", Integer.toString(limit));

}
```

FLAGS is a 1-byte bit mask and I'd like to select only the rows which has the second bit (position 1) of the mask on. The mask (Flow.FLOW_TYPE) is 0b00000010 and the type parameter can be either 0 or 1. It should work but it doesn't: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `query` function accepts only strings as parameters, but in SQLite, numbers and strings never compare equal (unless you have [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), but this works only for column values, not expressions).

You have to explicitly convert the parameters back to a number:

```
((...) >> 1 = CAST(? AS INTEGER)) AND ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer!