# Does PDO SQLite support where clauses on mathematical operations?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

First of all, I'm sorry for the phrasing of the question.

I have the following table `Testing` in a SQLite database :

```
| id | name  | something_numerical |
|----|-------|---------------------|
| 1  | test1 | 100                 |
| 2  | test2 | 500                 |
| 3  | test3 | 1000                |
| 4  | test4 | 5000                |
| 5  | test5 | 10000               |
| 6  | test6 | 25000               |
```

All queries are executed from `7.3.12-1+0~20191128.49+debian9~1.gbp24559b`

The following alias is used in the query (which seems to be the problem somehow)

```sql
something_numeric+100 AS modified_column
```

Querying via PDO **without** placeholders **works** as expected and returns rows 3 and 4.

```sql
SELECT *, something_numerical+100 AS modified_column 
FROM Testing 
WHERE modified_column BETWEEN 750 AND 7500
```

Querying via PDO **with** placeholders **returns no rows** and no errors. (I also tried using `?` for casting the parameters, with identical results)

```sql
SELECT *, something_numerical+100 AS modified_column 
FROM Testing 
WHERE modified_column BETWEEN :min_modified_column AND :max_modified_column
```

values

```php
$parameters = [
   ':min_modified_column'=>750,
   ':max_modified_column'=>7500
];
```

Without `+100` to the column `something_numerical`, both queries work as expected and return 3 and 4.

Here is the SQLite database to help in reproducing (if necessary)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Testing";
CREATE TABLE "Testing" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "name" text NOT NULL,
  "something_numerical" integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (1,  'test1',    100);
INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (2,  'test2',    500);
INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (3,  'test3',    1000);
INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (4,  'test4',    5000);
INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (5,  'test5',    10000);
INSERT INTO "Testing" ("id", "name", "something_numerical") VALUES (6,  'test6',    25000);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What happens if you leave the colons out of the `$parameters` keys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was a type casting issue.

Binding each of these parameters with the right type (`PDO::PARAM_INT`) solves the issue.

```php
$prepared_statement->bindValue(
    ':min_modified_column', 
    750, 
    \PDO::PARAM_INT
);
$prepared_statement->bindValue(
    ':max_modified_column', 
    7500, 
    \PDO::PARAM_INT
);
```

It would *seem* that, without any operation SQLite/PDO can infer the type from the column type, but can't do that anymore after an operation on its contents.

The following question got me on the right track

[Android/SQLite - Bit operation on WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211365/android-sqlite-bit-operation-on-where-clause)